# Reinstalling WAMP, file backup MySQL database w/ InnoDB tables = FILE COPY ok?

Tags: mysql, backup, innodb

I need to do a fresh install of WAMP. Files and other settings are easy to backup/reconfigure, but I have a question regarding MYSQL.

I used to simply COPY a backup of the mysql folder structure , data, and everything...

But w/ this project i'm using INNODB tables , and i've read that SIMPLY COPYING the data folder wont work w/ InnoDB, and will be pront to corruptions and such..

but I'm copying the wHOLE mysql folder , bin, data and all.  can't that work as well?

I dont understand why that can't work because, everything MYSQL needs to run normally is there in the MySQL folder w/c im copying completely, not just the DATA folder.... and as far as i know MYSQL doesnt have any other dependencies like REgistry settings or windows system file or other external stuffs to run normally -- DATA/Tables wise.

so if my above assumptions are correct, then backing up my database/tables by copying the WHOLE mysql folder = 100% ok , yes?

Now i know there are other ways to backup database, like mysql Dumps and other stuff, but that's a lot of work vs just copying the darn thing, since i have access to the root anyway.

please advise. thanks

Comment: could be the ticket. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49271/backup-localhost-wamp-database-phpmyadmin-from-harddrive-files-on-windows-f

Comment: i myself would test the theory on another box. burn a CD with it all, install it on machine B. stop WAMP of course prior to the burn.

Comment: actually i tested it and it worked. the reason why im asking is that i dont want any surprises later.. it may work now but if i do somet sort of update or whatever it will error and i'd spend so much time trying to figure out stuff but it's basically just corruption of some sort..= nightmare scenario 

hence i hope someone can confirm

Comment: well, i changed the drive letter of my drive where i put my wamp.. drive D: to E: 
then , i COPIED the wamp folder from E: (former D:) to the new D: basically testing if FILECOPY would work. and it did.. but im still fearful of surprises lol

Comment: @DrewPierce lol...aite..ima run w/ this.. if things F up im coming back to haunt you :P

Comment: what ?! it was your idea. wait, no, i said fear not

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can copy MySql Folder. For the InnoDB tables there is one log file inside mysql>>data folder. Do not forget to move log file "ibdata1" inside your newly installed XAMPP/WAMP data folder, the tables will work. MyISAM tables will not cause any problems at all. Best of luck !!

Comment: Just tried this and mine wouldn't work until I deleted ibtmp1 in the target folder too

Answer (score 0):

Even when is deinstalling, files that are not installation files eg. newly created files in process of work with projects will NOT be deleted.
I had situation today that WAMP stopped because of some error with *wampserver.ini* file. 
There was no chance to restart it. 
As I am currently in the middle of project, I needed right WAMP installation as fast as possible. 
I made whole backup of C:\wamp folder, and started deinstallation.
After that all files with full folder up tree was there: WWW, bin\mysql\mysql5.x.xx.
But there is mismatch with MySQL versions so this could be solution - installing previous 
version of MySQL and backup all DBs. I think I am going to do that after current work.